# Windows IPSec Filter Sanity Check

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ipsec

I'm installing [NSClient++](http://nsclient.org/nscp/) so our Nagios system can monitor some windows servers using NRPE. I need to punch a hole in our IPSec policy to allow inbound connections on port 5666 from the Nagios server.

I find the Windows IPSec IP filter a bit counter intuitive at times (IP Tables is more my bag), so I'm wondering if someone from the community could confirm that the `add filter` command below does actually configure the following rule:

Rule:

```
Allow inbound connections to port 5666 from remote host 172.16.3.200
```

These are the `netsh` commands I used:

```
netsh ipsec static add filter filterlist="NAGIOS NSClient" 
      srcaddr=172.16.3.200 srcport=0 
      dstaddr=ME dstport=5666 
      mirrored=yes 
      description="Inbound" 
      protocol=TCP
```

I then add this to an existing IPSec policy rule using:

```
netsh ipsec static add rule name=NAGIOS 
      filterlist="NAGIOS NSClient"  
      filteraction=Permit 
      policy=CorePolicy
```

I did test by trying to connect to this windows server from two different machines and the rules seem to work, but for my own sanity it would be nice for someone to cast their expert eye over the above, just in case.